# Masking/Hashing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As SQL dba, I need to export data which have some personal/sensitive information such as the national identification number (NiN). This field is a 10-digits unique number and it's not allowed as per our company's policy to export such data. Is there anyway I can generate a new field out of NiN but with different value and same length. I need this value to be consistent across all tables so that we can use this new field to JOIN data instead of using NiN.

I am thinking of `HashBytes` function but it generates an output with different length (10 digits).

Data is huge, so it's important to **avoid collision**. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you limited to 10 digits for your new field?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would change the format of the produced value to be *different* from the internal version.  That will make it much simpler to see right away if there is an issue.

Second, you can use a hashing algorithm such as sha256 which is quite unlikely to have conflicts.  That might be good enough.

Third, you need to think through the security requirements better.  My preferred solution is to have a look-up table that matches internal numbers to external values.  Then, this table is used for all exports and imports to translate between the two.  A suggestion here would be to use `newid()` to generate the value and to use GUIDs for external data.

However, this may not be sufficient for your requirements.  Why?  The same number has the same value over time.  So, although you might be able to hide the internal value and even forget it, a given external value still still matches to a single number -- tying external records together.

The solution to this is something called "salt" in the hashing function.  This allows the external value to change over time, while still mapping to the same internal number.